# Limit Product Title Characters before cut-off in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm having trouble with my magento store's layout. Some products with long titles would get cut off with a '...' but sometimes the title won't get cut off the title and instead throw out my layout's positioning. I have attached a photo

[Photo of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfk5t.png)

I have tried the substr function in app/design/frontend/interface/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
but it just ended up cutting the product's name in the actual page of the product, not the full view like the image above shows. I just need the '...' to happen without as many characters to prevent it going to a new line and ruining the layout.

Comment: You need to show the existing code that produces this issue and your related CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Use this trick in PHP, use substr function :
Go to **template > catalog > products > list.phtml** file and update product name code with this code

```
<?php
    // define the maximum length of the product name here
    $maxLength = 10;
    $productName = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name');
    echo substr($productName, 0, $maxLength).'...';
?>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I also used this for the short description in list view.  `<?php $maxLength = 150;  $productName = $_product->getShortDescription();  echo substr($productName, 0, $maxLength).'...';  ?>`